# How do i build and application that works as both OSGI bundles and a WAR

Tags: dependency-injection, osgi, war

I am developing and application as a series of OSGI bundles which will run on Karaf.
The Bundles has a fair bit of interoperability, both exposing a bunch of services, and consuming services from each other.

However, I would very much like to be able to build a WAR file of the application alongside the bundles. There are a few clients that quite simply won't allow an OSGI container on their servers.

So my question is, what is the best way to separate the OSGI service logic from the application logic? The activators are no trouble, as they are just unused in the WAR deployment, but i have a lot of calls that retrives services from the bundlecontext, like `bundleContext.getServiceReference(stuffISortOfNeed.class)`scattered around my code. bundleContext is currently a static object set by the activator.

This won't do in a WAR container that knows nothing of OSGI.

Is it possible to somehow hide the BundleContext and the getServiceReference calls away from the actual application? Preferably i would love an injection-like approach where i could define my services with @Annotations and define and injector for OSGI and one for PlainOldJava.

Answer (score 2):

To really have POJOs you could use *Blueprint XML* to register your *Web Application Bundle (WAB)*.
A good example can be found in the [pax web project](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/master/samples/whiteboard-blueprint/src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/blueprint/blueprint.xml).

By using XML over annotations you only have an extra resource file that can be ignored if you assemble you bundles as libs in a war file, no extra dependencies on specific annotations.